# Not able to select a value from drop down using Index in Testcafe

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Below is my code. I am able to access and select the item from drop down from a  browser console using

```
  '''document.querySelector('#__next > div > main > div.Home_toolbar__JY_RL > 
  div.Home_deviceControls__nQw4V > select:nth-child(2)').selectedIndex = 3'''
```

But from test in testcafe from below code -

```
''test('Select each available Audio input device', async (browser) => {
await browser.wait(6000);
let audioDevices = Selector('#__next > div > main > 
div.Home_toolbar__JY_RL > div.Home_deviceControls__nQw4V > 
select:nth-child(2)'
).selectedIndex = 3
await browser.expect(audioDevicescount.selectedIndex).eql(3);
});'''
```

Below is the error I get -

TypeError: Cannot set property selectedIndex of function __$$clientFunction$$() {
const testRun = builder._getTestRun();
const callsite...... } which has only a getter

I tried using client function, but could not pass the selectedIndex value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set the 'selectedIndex' property using the Selector, since the Selector is created for element querying. To modify the element state on the client side, use the [ClientFunctions](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402832/guides/basic-guides/obtain-client-side-info#import-functions-to-be-used-as-client-function-dependencies) mechanism.
I created a sample that demonstrates how to set selectedIndex using the ClientFunction. Please see the code below:

```
<select>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

```
import { Selector, ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';

fixture `f`
    .page `index.html`;

const select = Selector('select');

const setSelectedIndex = ClientFunction(index => {
    select().selectedIndex = index;
}, { dependencies: { select } });

test(`t`, async t => {
    await setSelectedIndex(2);

    await t.expect(select.selectedIndex).eql(2);
});
```